# cordova platform add android gives the error: "Error: The provided path is not an Android project."

Tags: android, cordova

When I run the command, I get the error:

> C:\Users\me\adtworkspace\project1>cordova platform add android [Error:
>   The provided path
>   "C:\Users\me\adtworkspace\project1\platforms\android" is not an
>   Android project.]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: paste the full command with path here

Comment: C:\Users\me\adtworkspace\project1>cordova platform add android try this

Comment: Then I get this error: "[Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.]". Anyway I will update the path in the question to simplify, but that is not causing the problem.

Comment: Did you a find a solution to this? I am stuck at the same point for 3 days now, have tried almost everything.

Comment: @ANANT I actually moved on to use phonegap build, so I did not try to fix this anymore. That's why I can't really mark any of these answers as correct.

Comment: For me what solved this issue was removing the platform and adding back again.   `cordova platform remove android` then `cordova platform add android`

Answer (score 43):

Yes it's indeed a Cordova Metadata issue. So Krystofs' answer is correct.
Where: The *"right thing"* to do is, to give a

`# cordova platform rm <platform>`

command :)
Then - afterwards - another adding of the plaform shall sort the issue

Comment: Thanks it's very useful. Worked fine. I suppose because there where 2 android versions on my computer.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem which I solved using the -d flag to show debug output

```
cordova -d platform add android
```

My debug output showed that I need to set a JAVA_HOME environment variable and then I needed to add JAVA and ANT to the path.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to do a "cordova -d platform add android", you'll probably see that it is because a prior error happened due to 
"**There is no script engine for file extension ".js"**".

Windows associated .js files with some other editors, so you have to disassociate this by typing:

**assoc .js=JSFILE**

After doing this, just run the add platform ("cordova platform add android") command again and it should work fine.

Comment: This worked for me except that after running this, I just deleted the ios folder inside platforms and ran phonegap build ios (I'm using phonegap instead of cordova).

Answer (score 4):

Delete C:/users/yourusername/.cordova and run command again, files are propably corrupted, it fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 1):

**For cordova 3.x users:**

Create ".cordova" file at root in the project.

"isCordova" returns true if finds ".cordova" file at line 42
https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/cordova-3.1.x/src/util.js

---

"Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project." causes at line 31 in plugin.js
https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/cordova-3.1.x/src/plugin.js

Comment: I was getting the same error when trying to add the camera plugin. Based on this post I thought maybe cordova was looking for a directory or something that it wasn't finding. (I had been working on the projects and been deleting un-needed stuff.)  So I created a complete cordova project in a dummy directory then compared the defaults with my project; dragged and dropped the missing file and folder into my project; and the add plugin thing ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening when you missing some files in your android platform folder in your cordova project.

Same thing can happen with the windows projects as well.

Visual Studio or Cordova engine has the capability  of  creating platform directories even if you delete them. But in this case the folder was there and it had some files in it. So the best solutions for this issue is trying one of these steps.

Clean your project. ( Visual Studio )
Rebuild your project ( Visual Studio )
Delete platform directory that you have the issue and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same but building for iOS.
I had an old build within the `platforms` folder. Try deleting it, then build again:

```
phonegap build [ios/android]
```

Hope this helps!