# Error in Building android app in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am fresh in ionic and trying to build a new app by following their  [official documentation](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/). It is all working fine till adding the android platform. But when i tries to build it like

```
$ ionic build android
```

It says

```
The provided path "/home/user/myApp/platforms/android" is not an Android project.
```

myApp is the demo 'tab app' from ioic which is downloaded by

```
$ ionic start myApp tabs
```

How should i solve this?

Answer (score 3):

you have to add the platform first to the project:

```
ionic platform add android
```

after, you have to check if you have a new folder created at:

```
yourProject/platforms/android.
```

If you want for ios, this is the command:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

Comment: yes i already done all these, and i m having that android folder too.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the problem, I do these steps to solve it:

1. Ionic platform rm Android
2. Go to the project folder, and delete the platforms directory, this is the key point.
3. Ionic platform add Android
4. Ionic build Android

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are staying at folder "`/home/user/myApp`" when add android platform

```
$ cd myApp
$ ionic platform add android
```

Comment: Yes. I am inside myApp

Comment: I'm not sure the real solution without see more detail. But hope this [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/179#issuecomment-70047075) can help. @colllin say he update cordova to latest version.

Comment: I can give you whatever details you need

Comment: Hey @HariKrishnan, Did you update cordova like my provided link and still error?. if yes, try another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479601/cordova-platform-add-android-gives-the-error-error-the-provided-path-is-not-a#answer-19908706), and show me the created android project after added.